# I want to get the relative index of a column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, indexing, pandas

I want to make a new column of the 5 day return for a stock, let's say. I am using pandas dataframe. I computed a moving average using the rolling_mean function, but I'm not sure how to reference lines like i would in a spreadsheet (B6-B1) for example. Does anyone know how I can do this index reference and subtraction?

sample data frame:

```
day    price    5-day-return
1      10          -
2      11          -
3      15          -
4      14          -
5      12          -
6      18          i want to find this ((day 5 price) -(day 1 price) )
7      20          then continue this down the list
8      19
9      21 
10     22
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you wanting this:

```
In [10]:

df['5-day-return'] = (df['price'] - df['price'].shift(5)).fillna(0)
df
Out[10]:
   day  price  5-day-return
0    1     10             0
1    2     11             0
2    3     15             0
3    4     14             0
4    5     12             0
5    6     18             8
6    7     20             9
7    8     19             4
8    9     21             7
9   10     22            10
```

[`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas.Series.shift) returns the row at a specific offset, we use this to subtract this from the current row. [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html#pandas.Series.fillna) fills the `NaN` values which will occur prior to the first valid calculation.